# How to apply css styling on rewards points notification email in opencart 2.0.1.1?

Tags: html, css, email, opencart2.x

When a customer gets rewards points he gets notified by email.
The default email contains only these lines :

```
You have received 200 Reward Points!

Your total number of reward points is now 200.
```

I know this text is in language file at

```
/admin/language/english/mail/customer.php
$_['text_reward_received']      = 'You have received %s Reward Points!';
 $_['text_reward_total']         = 'Your total number of reward points is now %s.';
```

I need to apply some css styling on this email notification relative to my opencart store. I tried adding html and css in this customer.php language file but it won't work.
I don't have any idea how can I apply styling i want. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your html tag & css & css class in language file for that.

**For Example:**

```
$_['text_reward_received']      = 'You have received %s <span style="font-size:15px; color:red;">Reward Points</span>!';
$_['text_reward_total']         = 'Your <span class="mystyle">total number</span> of reward points is now %s.';
```